# wcf wshttpbinding with username and password validator ProtocolException+XmlException

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

i have a wcf service with this config at server side :

```
WSHttpBinding wshttp = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
wshttp.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
wshttp.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
wshttp.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;

wshttp.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
wshttp.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
wshttp.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
wshttp.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
wshttp.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;

wshttp.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = 
    System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15;
wshttp.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
CustomBinding cb = new CustomBinding(wshttp);
var clockSkew = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
SymmetricSecurityBindingElement security = 
    cb.Elements.Find<SymmetricSecurityBindingElement>();
security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;

// Get the 
// System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens
//    .SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters 
SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters secureTokenParams = 
    (SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters)
        security.ProtectionTokenParameters;

// From the collection, get the bootstrap element.
SecurityBindingElement bootstrap = 
    secureTokenParams.BootstrapSecurityBindingElement;

// Set the MaxClockSkew on the bootstrap element.
bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;

EndpointAddress ea = 
    new EndpointAddress(
        new Uri("http://localhost:80/MyService"), 
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(
                                        "MyService Certeficate"));

isarService.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(ServiceLayer.IService),
        cb, 
        new Uri("http://localhost:80/MyService")).Address = ea;


isarService.Open();
```

and half of config is in app file like this :

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="SL.Service">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="
                  mexHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration=""
          name="MexHttpEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/MyService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" 
                             maxConcurrentInstances="100" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication customCertificateValidatorType="" 
                              certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="MyService Certeficate" 
                                storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" />
            <userNameAuthentication 
                userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ServiceLayer.CUAPValidator,ServiceLayer" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

i log my client error and they send log file to me for fix their app.application work for lots of my clients but some of them have this error :

**System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException** -> There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.

**System.Xml.XmlException** -> The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

i do not know when 99 client work well with this config why 3 of them has this problem !

**Question :**

please help me for fix this issue with easiest way.

**information :**

i host my service with windows service .

**EDIT 1:**

I Log Error Exact With svc log on client side . then i read error and error was that. in server side i do not see error in log . i do not what is exact different but seems the different is internet connection i mean proxy server or vpn etc .

**EDIT 2:**

Can this happen for .net version ?? because the version 4 has some update on it .

**EDIT 3:**

see this error its same with other perhaps help

The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '
Error Message

A {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #005a80; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
A:hover {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #0d3372; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
TD {
    FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
TD.titleBorder {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 0px solid; COLOR: #955319; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; TEXT-ALIGN: left
}
TD.titleBorder_x {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 0px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 1px solid; COLOR: #978c79; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGR'.

AND Inner Error :

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: What is different on those clients? Also, did you try to enable wcf trace and review it with SvcTraceViewer.exe?

Comment: Are your client configs similar on working and not working pcs?

Comment: yes every thing is similar but just my partners in office have network ip for connect like this : http://10.10.10.10\myservice but for other client in other city i have like http://80.190.11.10\myservice